# Unable to register new passkeys for Android 13 with error message "Your encrypted data is locked on this device"

Tags: chrome-for-android, google-account, google-pixel-6, android-13

I was experimenting with the passkey support for Chrome on Android when I came upon this error while registering a new passkey:

> #### Your encrypted data is locked on this device
>
> For security, you can no longer access your encrypted data on this device. Try again using a device you've recently used to sign in to your Google Account.
>
> Visit https://g.co/OnDeviceEncryption to learn more.

<sup>[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NMUol.png)</sup>

I am running Android 13 using a Google Pixel phone. I believe that Google uses Google Password Manager to save the passkeys. But, I am not sure how to correct this. I have tried to sign in to another phone with the same account, but this keeps on happening.

Comment: Have you tried enabling "on-device encryption" on the phone first? Open Chrome \ Settings \ Password Manager \ Settings \ Click Set up under On-device encryption.

Comment: I have the same issue on Galaxy S23. Trying to enable On-device encryption fails authenticating Google account with fingerprint, but succeeded with manually entering password. Adding new passkey still fails though.

Comment: Same issue with Google Password Manager on Motorola Edge and HP Envy PC