# "Your encrypted data is locked on this device" error message

Tags: encryption, system-error

The question is simple, I just want to know what does below message means?

> #### Your encrypted data is locked on this device
>
> For security, you can no longer access your encrypted data on this device. Try again using a device that you’ve recently used to sign in to your Google Account.

Comment: It means what it says. You have probably tried too many times with an incorrect login. Follow the instructions to fix it.

Comment: Related, but not answered yet: [Unable to register new passkeys for Android 13 with error message "Your encrypted data is locked on this device"](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249571/44325).