# WhatsApp passkey - On device encryption locked

Tags: google, passkey

I was trying to enable the passkey feature but I get an error message that says that the encrypted data on this device is locked. I'm not sure what it means, I have read that usually the password manager has this issue but I'm able to access without issues.

Comment: Duplicate, but not answered yet: [Unable to register new passkeys for Android 13 with error message "Your encrypted data is locked on this device"](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249571/44325).